# Prevent sendmail from doing dns lookups before relaying

Tags: sendmail

My machine (CentOS, sendmail-8.14.7-5.el7) accepts emails from machines and forwards all of them to my smarthost `my-smarthost.mydomain.com`, which in turn has several dynamic MX-records). Local mail stays local (using the alias-file).

```
sendmail.mc:
define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp:my-smarthost.mydomain.com')dnl
```

Today I noticed a problem:

```
# mailq
        /var/spool/mqueue (1 request)
-----Q-ID----- --Size-- -----Q-Time----- ------------Sender/Recipient-----------
02AG1YBC023172     1239 Tue Mar 10 17:01 <sender@some-domain.com>
      8BITMIME   (host map: lookup (non-domain.com): deferred)
                     <john.doe@non-domain.com>

# sendmail -v -q
Running /var/spool/mqueue/02AG1YBC023172 (sequence 1 of 1)
non-domain.com: Name server timeout
<john.doe@non-domain.com>... Transient parse error -- message queued for future delivery
```

Why does sendmail try to dns lookup the addresses inside the mails? I thought it just forwards everything non-local to the smarthost!

I tried to use the trick to disable DNS-lookup with

```
define(`confSERVICE_SWITCH_FILE',`/etc/mail/service.switch')dnl
```

and so on, but there is a problem with that: This also disables the MX-search for the smarthost! So the dynamic MX-records for my smarthost are no longer found/used!

Any ideas how to stop sendmail from doing anything except relaying to the smarthost?

Comment: How do you define non-local in your rules? If you are using an IP (or an IP, fqdn mixture) then `sendmail might need to resolve to evaluate the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [`FEATURE(nocanonify)`](https://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/features.html#nocanonify)

> **nocanonify** Don't pass addresses to $[ ... $] for canonification by default, i.e., host/domain names are considered canonical, except for unqualified names, which must not be used in this mode (violation of the standard). […]

It should stop sendmail from asking DNS about domains in header addresses.

Comment: Would you consider adding some words of explanation on why and how this solves the problem? Link-only-answers are often considered not so helpful and tend to get deleted ...

Comment: No, I didn't consider it because I was not aware that this option prevents the usage of DNS lookups for checking/canonification.
(Yes I didn't understand that "Don't pass addresses to $[ ... $] for canonification by default" means DNS lookups.)

But you are correct: If I set this feature sendmail works as expected!

Comment: This seems to have solved an issue I was having with a server that uses a smart relay host, Thanks!